# $\frac{1}{m(E)}\int _E f(x) dx\in S$ implies $f(x)\in S$ for a.e. $x$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-sets

The problem: Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ be closed, and let $f\in L^1 ([0,1], m)$, where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$. Assume that for all measurable $E\subset[0,1]$ with $m(E)>0$ we have $\frac{1}{m(E)}\int _E f(x) dx\in S$. Prove that $f(x)\in S$ for a.e. $x\in [0,1]$.

My progress: Currently I am trying to apply Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem (See Page 68 [Theorem 6.10](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/m206/ch5_measure_notes.pdf)) to prove the statement. But I am not very confident about this because in that case, $m(E) \to 0$ and I feel I miss a part to explain why I can still apply Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem. Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: See Rudin's RCA. Lebesgue differentiation theorem is an overkill for this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=theorem+1.40+Rudin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Papa Rudin theorem $1.40$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528602/papa-rudin-theorem-1-40)

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks! I will check the book and those posts. I use Folland’s book. Seem like I also need Rudin’s one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$
F=\{x\in [0,1]:f(x)\not\in S\}=f^{-1}([0,1]\setminus S).$ Then $S$ measurable. Since $G=[0,1]\setminus S$ open, then $G=\bigcup I_j$, $j\in J$ where $I_j$ are disjoint intervals, $J$ countable.

If $m(\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)\in G\})>0$, then  $m(\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)\in I_{j_0}\})>0$, for some $j_0\in J$. But, if $I_{j_0}=(a,b),$ then
$$
m(\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)\in I_{j_0}\})=\lim_{n\to\infty} 
m\Big(\Big\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)\in \Big(a+\frac1n,b-\frac1n\Big)\Big\}\Big).
$$
Hence, for some $n_0\in\mathbb N$,
$$
m\bigg(\bigg\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)\in 
\Big(a+\frac1n_0,b-\frac1n_0\Big)\bigg\}\bigg)>0
$$
In such case, if $E=\big\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)\in \big(a+\frac{1}{n_0},
b-\frac{1}{n_0}\big)\big\}$, then
$$
\frac{1}{m(E)}\int_E f\in \Big[a+\frac1n_0,b-\frac1n_0\Big]
$$
and $\big[a+\frac1{n_0},b-\frac1{n_0}\big]\cap S=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

To make it rigorous : let $N$ a null set (i.e. $m(N)=0$) s.t. $$\lim_{r\to 0^+)\to 0}\frac{1}{B_r(x)}\int_{B_r(x)} f(u)\,\mathrm d u=f(x),$$
for all $x\in [0,1]\setminus N$. Set $$E_n(x)=\frac{1}{|B_{1/n}(x)|}\int_{B_{1/n}(x)}f(u)\,\mathrm d u.$$
For all $x\in [0,1]\setminus N$, you have that $E_n(x)$ is a sequence of $S$ that converges to $f(x)$. Since $S$ is closed, it's sequentially closed and thus $f(x)\in S$.

Therefore $f(x)\in S$ for all $[0,1]\setminus S$, and thus $f(x)\in S$ a.e.

Comment: It was a FAQ (see comments above).

Answer (score 1):

This just extends Yiorgos' answer to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Proceed by contradiction, suppose there is some $f$ such that $f^{-1}(S^c)$ has positive measure.

Since $S$ is closed, we can write $S^c = \cup_k B(x_k, \epsilon_k)$, a countable union of non empty open balls. Then there must be some $k$ such that $f^{-1}(B(x_k, \epsilon_k))$ has positive measure. Hence there is some $\delta>0 $ such that $E=f^{-1}(B(x_k, \delta))$ has positive measure and $\delta< \epsilon_k$.

Now pick some $s \in S$, $b = x_k+ { \delta \over \|s -s_k \|}(s-x_k)$  and let $\phi(x) = \langle x-b, b -x_k \rangle$.

Then $\phi(f(x)) \le 0$ for all $x \in E$ and
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(s) &=& \langle s-b, b -x_k \rangle \\
&=& \langle s-x_k -(b-x_k), b -x_k \rangle \\
&=& \langle ({\|s-x_k\| \over \delta}-1)(b-x_k), b -x_k \rangle \\
&=& ({\|s-x_k\| \over \delta}-1) \delta^2 \\
&\ge& ({\epsilon_k \over \delta}-1) \delta^2 \\
&>& 0
\end{eqnarray}
Consequently, $\phi({1 \over m E} \int_E f dm) \le 0$ but $\phi(s) >0$ and so ${1 \over m E} \int_E f dm \notin S$.